# Loading data in Neo4j from csv

Tags: csv, upload, neo4j, cypher

I'm uploading iteratively nodes and edges from several csv files, one per node type. Loading nodes works well, but loading edges does not always work. Indeed, some of the nodes have numbers as identifiers - if so, all nodes of that type have numbers - but are loaded as strings, hence creating edges fail. Creating manually an edge adding wrapping the identifier with double quotes works well.

How can I either force LOAD CSV to use numbers for these identifiers while creating nodes, or force LOAD CSV to wrap identifiers with double quotes?

Article nodes:

```
Type    PMID    ArticleTitle    AbstractText    Date    Pages
Article 25358116    Synthesis of... Abstract    2014-10-30  
Article 25358093    Putting theory...   In this study...    2014-10-30  e1003910
```

Issue nodes:

```
Type    Name    Year    Month   Volume  Issue
Issue   J. Med. Chem., 2014 2014    Oct     
Issue   PLoS Comput. Biol., 2014, 10, 10    2014    Oct 10  10
Issue   PLoS ONE, 2014, 9, 10   2014        9   10
```

Edges:

```
Name    PMID
J. Med. Chem., 2014 25358116
PLoS Comput. Biol., 2014, 10, 10    25358093
```

Cypher commands:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Article(PMID);
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'article.nodes' as csvLine FIELDTERMINATOR '\t' CREATE (:Article { PMID: toInt(csvLine.PMID), Title: csvLine.ArticleTitle, Date: csvLine.Date, Pages: csvLine.Pages, AbstractText: csvLine.Abstract })  return count(*);
CREATE INDEX ON :Journal(Abbreviate);
CREATE INDEX ON :Issue(Name);
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'issue.nodes' as csvLine FIELDTERMINATOR '\t' CREATE (:Issue { Name: csvLine.Name, Volume: csvLine.Volume, Issue: csvLine.Issue, Year: csvLine.Year, Month: csvLine.Month})  return count(*);
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'article.edges' as csvLine FIELDTERMINATOR '\t' MATCH (src:Issue { Name: csvLine.Name }), (tgt:Article { PMID: toInt(csvLine.PMID) }) CREATE (src) -[:hasArticle]-> (tgt) return count(*);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After receiving your files, there was a formatting problem with the TSV.

Showing the csvLine at a whole in neo4j showed me null for Issue name, so I modified the format and reexport the file with google drive.

Also you can check for errors on CsvLINT http://csvlint.io/validation/545681456373761303020000

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Users/ikwattro/dev/playbox/pierre/article.edges' as csvLine FIELDTERMINATOR '\t' WITH csvLine LIMIT 10 RETURN csvLine 
I get this
Name PMID   J. Med. Chem., 2014 25358116 
﻿Name PMID  PLoS Comput. Biol., 2014, 10, 10 
﻿Name PMID  J. Med. Chem., 2014 
﻿Name PMID  J. Med. Chem., 2014
Name And PMID Are under the same key
```

Chris

Answer (score 1):

You can use toInt(csvline.id) for e.g. :

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-functions-scalar.html#functions-toint

Comment: Thanks. However I'm still having issues. I forced to numbers PMID of Article nodes and checked they were numbers, creating edges still return 0 with either PMID or toInt(PMID) in LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'article.edges' as csvLine FIELDTERMINATOR '\t' MATCH (src:Issue { Name: csvLine.Name }), (tgt:Article { PMID: toInt(csvLine.PMID )}) CREATE (src) -[:hasArticle]-> (tgt) return count(*)

Comment: Also, use toInt on both sides, when creating your nodes, and when matching nodes for creating the relationships

Comment: That's what I'm doing: LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'article.nodes' as csvLine FIELDTERMINATOR '\t' CREATE (:Article { PMID: toInt(csvLine.PMID), Title: csvLine.ArticleTitle, Date: csvLine.Date, Pages: csvLine.Pages, AbstractText: csvLine.Abstract })  return count(*); LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'article.edges' as csvLine FIELDTERMINATOR '\t' MATCH (src:Issue { Name: csvLine.Name }), (tgt:Article { PMID: toInt(csvLine.PMID)}) CREATE (src) -[:hasArticle]-> (tgt) return count(*); In the console the following cypher works: match (a:Article {PMID: 25358116}) return a;

Comment: can you provides 2 lines from the nodes and edges csv ? if it is not confidential ?

Comment: Type PMID ArticleTitle AbstractText Date Pages
Article 25358116 Synthesis... Abstract 2014-10-30 
Article 25358093 Putting... In recent... 2014-10-30 e1003910

Comment: Type Name Year Month Volume Issue
Issue J. Med. Chem., 2014 2014 Oct

Comment: Name PMID
J. Med. Chem., 2014 25358116

Comment: The above three comments are the Article and Issue node files and corresponding edges respectively.

Comment: Would you mine to create a gist with the data, copying it from here I can't get the right formatting and the nodes are empty of props ?

Comment: Or copying it in the Question box and format it with the code quotes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64134/discussion-between-user3195894-and-christophe-willemsen).